# Green's function for a 0+1 D wave equation in Milne coodinates

Tags: waves, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, greens-functions, quark-gluon-plasma

Consider a system in $3+1$ D Minkowski space with coordinates
$\tau,r,\theta,\eta$, $g^{\mu\nu} = (1,-1,-r^2,-\tau^2)$ with a metic given by
\begin{equation}
{
ds^2 = d\tau^2-dr^2 - r^2d\theta^2 - \tau^2 d\eta^2.
}
\end{equation}
The Milne coordinates $\tau$ and $\eta$ are given in terms of $t$
and $z$ as
\begin{align}
{
t = \tau \cosh{\eta} \\
z = \tau \sinh{\eta}
}
\end{align}

It is given that the system is symmetric along all space directions, i.e. $r, \theta,\eta$. The problem now is reduced to be of $0+1$ D.

I am now given an equation
\begin{align}{
D_{\mu}A^{\mu} = f
}
\end{align}
where $D_{\mu}$ is the covariant derivative. I want to convert this into the form
\begin{align}{
D_{\mu}D^{\mu}\phi = f
}
\end{align}
where $A^{\mu} =D^{\mu}\phi$ and $\phi$ is scalar. Assume, this can be done. Once I have this, my approach is to solve this using Green's function and get a solution
\begin{align}{
\phi = \int G(x_{\mu},x'_{\mu})f(x'_{\mu})d^{4}x'^{\mu}
}
\end{align}
where $\Sigma^{\mu}$ represents a boundary surface.

Now in $0+1$ D, the equivalent wave equation I have is
\begin{align}{
D_{\mu}D^{\mu}\phi = \partial_{\tau}(\tau\partial_{\tau}) \phi = 0
}
\end{align}
The above equation has the solution
\begin{align}{
\phi(\tau) = A + B\log{\tau}
}
\end{align}
I now want to find a Green's function for the above wave equation given the boundary conditions
\begin{align}{
\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\partial_{\tau}\phi = 0\\
\lim_{\tau\to\tau_0}\partial_{\tau}\phi = C = Const 
}
\end{align}
The first boundary condition above is satisfied by the general solution to the equation. So it doesn't uniquely determine the Green's function. However, if I demand Green's function to be symmetric w.r.t its variables I get
\begin{align}
G(\tau,\tau') &= C + \log{\tau'/\tau_0} && \tau_0 < \tau' < \tau \\
&= C + \log{\tau/\tau_0} && \tau < \tau' < \infty
\end{align}

I have doubts about the validity of what I have done, specifically whether I have computed the Green's function incorrectly. Did I use it outside the scope of its validity? Is my imposition of symmetry arbitrary? Are my boundary conditions 'good enough' for Green's function to exist for the given differential equation?